# How to update a vue js array with user inputed value

Tags: vue.js

i am creating a web app which has a table that displays information from an array i have created using vue.js. i wanted to be able to edit/update/delete the content of the array based on the needs of an admin account which would then change what the table is displaying.
my current array

```js
var app2 = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        search: '',
        courses: [
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x', },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x',  },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x',  },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x',},
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x', },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x',  },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x', },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x!', },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x',  },
            { 'topic': 'x', 'description': 'x!', }
        ]
    }
```

i would like the "x" to be changeable based on what the user typed into the input field

```html
<th scope="row"> 1</th>
<td>{{item.topic}}</td>
<td>{{item.description}}</td>
```

this isnt all the code the gist of it

Comment: Paste more code you have prepared or a gist link so that we can review your problem. This is not enough information at the moment.

Comment: Is your issue the basic of communication? Someone needs to know something - either he has to ask or he gets told. (fetch or push)

Comment: @Gander  codepen.io/N3WTYPE01/pen/rNNRVVv essentially an input field that will change the content of topic and description

Comment: @N3WTYPE something like this? https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/BaabWqy

Comment: @steve16351 omg yes this is what i was trying to do. i didn't expect anyone to do the actual coding thank you. going through it there is stuff i haven't covered yet such as $emit but functionally its exactly what i wanted to do. its late here so ill go through it more tomorrow but this is really helpful thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is a component which you toggle to be either in a read-only mode, or in a mode which accepts input for your admin users. You can then use this in your `v-for` loop to bind to the array of data.

You can still use `v-model` with custom components to facilitate two-way binding as described [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). Basically, `v-model` will supply the value to the component via the `value` property, and will listen for an `input` event from the component to receive updates to the value.

So, our component template could look like the below, which conditionally renders an input field if the prop `edit` is true, otherwise it renders a read-only span element. We bind the value of the `input` to a local mutable data item we initialise from the `value` prop `v-model` will pass in from the parent. On the `input` event as the user changes the value, it will in turn emit an event of the same name so the parent component can receive updates.

```html
<input 
     v-if="edit" 
     type="text" 
     v-model="localValue" 
     @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)" 
     class="form-control" />
<span v-else>{{ value }}</span>
```

With a backing script like this:

```js
var customInputComponent = {
  template: '#input-template',
  props: ["edit", "value"],
  data() { 
    return {
      localValue: this.value
    }
  }
};
```

In the parent element, the usage of the component in the template would look like this, where we register the custom input component with the name `appCustomInput`. We use `v-model` to bind the component to the current item of the iteration and the property for that particular column. Finally, we bind the `edit` prop of the custom component to a data field `editMode` on the parent with `:edit="editMode"` (short cut for `v-bind:edit="editMode"`).

It is important to set the `:key="searchResult.id"` to uniquely identify each entry, otherwise there will be problems when updating the DOM when the value changes. We can't use just the `index` for this, because if we remove an item from the courses array, it will no longer be correct. So, I've added a unique `id` property to each of the course objects.

```html
<tr v-for="(searchResult, index) in searchCourses" :key="searchResult.id">
    <th scope="row"> 
      {{ index + 1 }}            
    </th>
    <td>
      <app-custom-input v-model="searchResult.topic" :edit="editMode" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <app-custom-input v-model="searchResult.description" :edit="editMode" />
    </td>
    <td v-if="editMode">
      <button 
              v-if="editMode" 
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              @click="deleteRow(searchResult.id)">Delete</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The backing instance code for this would look something like this:

```js
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
      appCustomInput: customInputComponent
    },    
    data: {
      search: '',
      editMode: false,
      courses: [  
        { topic: "English", description: "Universal language", id: 1 },
        { topic: "Maths", description: "Numbers etc.", id: 2 },
        { topic: "Physics", description: "Falling apples etc.", id: 3 },
        { topic: "Chemistry", description: "Periodic table etc.", id: 4 }
      ]    
    },
    methods: {
      deleteRow(sourceId) {
        var index = this.courses.findIndex(a => a.id == sourceId);
        this.courses.splice(index, 1);
      }
    },
    computed: {
      searchCourses() { 
        return this.courses
        .filter((item) => {
          return item.topic
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

A complete code pen is available [here](https://codepen.io/steve16351/pen/BaabWqy) for demonstration.

Comment: Again ty for all your help you went above and beyond explaining each section ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

The `{{ }}` "mustache" syntax is used to display values, so the expression between the double braces will be evaluated and the output will replace it. This is a one-way process. You're most likely looking for a two-way binding which does not only change your UI if the property changs, but also change the property when a user changes it from the UI, hence the name.

Have a look at [Input bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage). Where `v-model` is the key:

```
<input v-model="item.topic">
```

Comment: hello ty fo reply i understand using v-model to 2 way bind but im just not sure how it would replace inside the table. i copied the page code onto codepen https://codepen.io/N3WTYPE01/pen/rNNRVVv but when i try adding the v-model="item.topic" to input inside my app it breaks the whole page

Comment: I modified your codepen to include an input field to change the items https://codepen.io/memetolsen/pen/ExxMeeb. But as far as I can see, someone else answered this question in more detail.